# ActiveMQ 5.11 network of brokers and master/slave group config

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, master-slave, amq

In ActiveMQ /A-MQ 5.11, I want to build a broker topology of:

- 4 master/slave pairs (2 in Las Vegas, 2 in New York)
- network of brokers
- complete graph (each master connected to all other masters)

  [Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_A-MQ/6.2/html-single/Fault_Tolerant_Messaging/#FMQFaultTolNetwork) says each broker should connect to other master/slave groups using `masterSlave` URI:

> ```
> <networkConnectors>
> <networkConnector
>    uri="masterslave:(tcp://masterHost:61002,tcp://slaveHost:61002)"/>    
> </networkConnectors>
> ```

..so for this topology,

[image]

..the `networkConnectors` for master/slave pairs in Las Vegas (NY omitted for brevity) should be:

**vegas-A1,A2**...connected to B,C,D master/slave groups

> ```
> <networkConnectors>
>   <networkConnector name="groupBLink" uri="masterslave:(tcp://vegas-B1:61001,tcp://vegas-B2:61001)"/>
>   <networkConnector name="groupCLink" uri="masterslave:(tcp://ny-C1:61001,tcp://ny-C2:61001)"/>
>   <networkConnector name="groupDLink" uri="masterslave:(tcp://ny-D1:61001,tcp://ny-D2:61001)"/>           
> </networkConnectors>
> ```

**vegas-B1,B2**...connected to A,C,D master/slave groups

> ```
> <networkConnectors>
>   <networkConnector name="groupALink" uri="masterslave:(tcp://vegas-A1:61001,tcp://vegas-A2:61001)"/>
>   <networkConnector name="groupCLink" uri="masterslave:(tcp://ny-C1:61001,tcp://ny-C2:61001)"/>
>   <networkConnector name="groupDLink" uri="masterslave:(tcp://ny-D1:61001,tcp://ny-D2:61001)"/>           
> </networkConnectors>
> ```

### Question

Is this configuration correct?

Comment: Can this be done with shared file system for all the brokers?

Comment: A single master with `n` slaves should use a shared file system; separate NFS4 volumes for each M/S group is sufficient. Do NOT use the same shared file system across all brokers; doing so would result to single master; partition using volumes.

Comment: Nice job! In this group config what would be the urls that clients going to use ? tcp://:vegasA1, tcp://vegasA2,  tcp://:vegasB1, tcp://vegasB2, ....and all needs to be listed?

Comment: @RezaFarshi Yes, you list all brokers `failover:(tcp://:vegasA1:61616, tcp://vegasA2:61616,tcp://:vegasB1:61616,...)`

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering, the above configuration was tested and confirmed to work for full graph/mesh networks in ActiveMQ.